# Connecting to netlify on localhost with chrome and firefox

Tags: cassandra, netlify, datastax-astra, netlify-cli

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8COh40v2jU&t=66s).

At 55:39 Ania is able to connect to her localhost:8888/.netlify port to see the records she has read from the graphql playground.

I am trying to do the same but cannot connect to the page. I have tried in both chrome and firefox and in both cases, I get a connection refused error message.

My firewall has permitted access for both chrome and firefox, and I even tried disabling the firewall. The error still returns.

I tried it without my vpn turned on.

I have logged into netlify (I have nothing on github yet, so it's just a local deployment).

Is there something special I need to do to be able to run local host with netlify?

The full text of the error message is:

> This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Check your Internet connection Check any cables
> and reboot any routers, modems or other network devices you may be
> using. Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or
> antivirus settings. If it is already listed as a program allowed to
> access the network, try removing it from the list and adding it again.
> If you use a proxy server… Check your proxy settings or contact your
> network administrator to make sure that the proxy server is working.
> If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to
> Applications > System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and
> deselect any proxies that have been selected.

In relation to #1, I am connected to the internet. I can run the local host on port 3000 and get the react app to load. it does not read anything from graphql. When I console log the datastax data from the react app, I get null as a result (where Ania gets the records created in the first hour of the tutorial).

In relation to #2, chrome and firefox are both added to my firewall

In relation to #3, no proxies are used - except the box to use FTP Mode PASV is checked. I tried unchecking it but it makes no difference.

I tried adding the local host 8888 url as a Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains in my system preferences - but it makes no difference.

My console shows:

> ◈ Netlify Dev ◈ ◈ Ignored general context env var: LANG (defined in
> process) ◈ Injected .env file env var: ASTRA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT ◈
> Injected .env file env var: ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN ◈ Loaded
> function getGenres
>
> http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/getGenres. ◈ Functions server
> is listening on 55302 ◈ Starting Netlify Dev with Create React App $
> react-scripts start (node:55384)
> [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning:
> 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the
> 'setupMiddlewares' option. (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show
> where the warning was created) (node:55384)
> [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE]
> DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated.
> Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option. Starting the development
> server...
>
> Compiled successfully!
>
> You can now view nextflix-datastax-clone in the browser.
>
> Local:            http://localhost:3000   On Your Network:
> http://10.0.0.1:3000
>
> Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a
> production build, use yarn build.
>
> webpack compiled successfully

ONE CLUE: I have cleaned my mac, I have cleared my cache (don't know why this would have worked since localhost 3000 loads the react app, but without the datastax data). A little box appears on my mac that says 'verifying AID.dylib'. I understand dylib means a shared database (maybe this some sort of Datastax reference? The process has been running almost 48 hours and the progress bar is at about 10%. Whatever that program is, it hasn't been verified. I wonder if this is why I can't load localhost:8888/.netifly in the same way that Ania can?

ANOTHER CLUE: I just found this post: https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/3617 which suggests that Netlify can't read functions in v17. I don't know if that's still current. I'm currently stuck in my efforts to check if this is the source of the problem because my brew commands wont run in my terminal. I think this may be because of some incompatibility with the macOS Monteray upgrade that I just installed. I will update this post if I find a way to configure my computer to be able to follow a basic beginner's tutorial.

Comment: just to check that functions are working, try hitting a function via `http://localhost:{functionPort}/.netlify/functions/getGenres`...

Comment: Tip: This has nothing to do with firewall etc. `netlify dev` does 3 things. Starts your react app, starts a functions server, and then creates a proxy handler that allows for the react app to access the functions server. Note the message ` Functions server is listening on 55302` in the output you shared. This means that the functions are running on port 55302. If you can access them on their port it means the netlify dev is having issues with setting up the proxy handler... I dont think same issue as one you mentioned. but check your node versions `node --version`.